# How to change a dropdown laravel collective when another dropdown value changed using jQuery or javascript

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I want to change towns dropdown values when cities dropdown selected value changes, each city has some towns bounded to it, I have a database contains two tables cities table and towns table, each town has a relation to the city it belongs to through a foreign key in the towns table. I've passed all the cites and towns from the controller to the view.

`Cities` table

```
id - name
```

`Towns` table

```
id - name - cityId --> (foreign key refering to id in Cities table)
```

Controller function

```
public function create()
{
    $cities = City::all();
    $towns = Town::all();

    return view('userAnnouncements.createAnnouncement')->with(['cities' => $cities, 'towns' => $towns]);
}
```

View

```
              <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row" dir="rtl">
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            {{ Form::label("المحافظة","المحافظة") }} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" dir="rtl">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @php
                                $citiesNames = array();
                                $townsNames = array();
                                foreach($cities as $city){ 
                                    $citiesNames[] = $city->name; 
                                }
                            @endphp
                            {{ Form::select('city', $citiesNames, null, ['class' => 'target', 'placeholder' => 'أختر المحافظة']) }}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row" dir="rtl">
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            {{ Form::label("المدينة","المدينة") }}  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" dir="rtl">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            {{ Form::select('town', $townsNames, null, ['class' => 'townDropdown', 'placeholder' => 'أختر مدينة']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am using Laravel 5.6, any help?

Comment: Now create some javascript.

Comment: ok how to get the selected value from the city dorpdown and where to write the javascript code in a separate file or in the same view file